# How to make common shell script not depend on system

Tags: shell

I have a question.

is possible to write shell script which doesn't depend on both ARCH and OS.
I want to make common shell script which works in hpUnix, linux, soalris and spark.

which shell do I use ? in my situation.

Please help me.

PS) thank you for reading my question.

Comment: What works in `dash` that most likely will work in other _Bourne-ish_ shells: it was created with the intention to have the absolute minimum functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Read this http://homepage.smc.edu/morgan_david/linadmin/labs/primitiveshells/primitive-shells.htm

> Though the most fundamental operating system in computer science, development of UNIX over its 40 years has split and branched into a thousand variations
>
> Under this umbrella of shifting unices lie shells, and they too are
>   both various and shifting. The main shells you will encounter are:
>
> The Korn shell (ksh and its derivatives mksh and pdksh) stemming from
>
> the AT&T camp  the C shell (csh and its derivative tcsh) originating
>   at Berkeley
>
> the Bourne again shell (bash) from GNU project, and
>   various other efforts like
>
> the Z shell (zsh) from a Princeton
>   University student,
>
> and the Almquist shell (ash) and derivative Debian
>   Almquist shell (dash).
>
> These are all basic shells, in common, but are by no means the same as one another and by no means behave identically. In fact, feature change was the precise historical reason for the various development branches. Behavior difference is why we have a range of shells, and that's why shells don't behave exactly the same. Don't expect them to. If this comparison of command shells is the map, then you can see clearly that they are all over the map. Programs in the command shell category are as similar and different as are, more familiarly, programs in the web browser category like Mosaic, Opera, Safari, Firefox, Chrome.

And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells

Answer (score 0):

So the proper tool for a multi-platform task is something that will run the same on all, like java.  Using such a solution is the only way to write it once.

You can write a shell script to do as above but you will quickly be having if/else chains for each ARCH/OS you want to support, requiring further and more complex testing.

You can then write an install script that will unpack your jar, and install a simple script to call your complex java.  Lots of examples how to make an executable jar are about the internet.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This questions:

[#!/bin/sh vs #!/bin/bash for maximum portability](https://serverfault.com/q/865874/94862)

[When must I use #!/bin/bash and when #!/bin/sh?](https://superuser.com/q/1133187/284722)

Could give you more details about why is preferred to use **#! /bin/sh**

Summarizing some points:

- There are several shells which implement a superset of the POSIX sh specification. On different systems, **/bin/sh** might be a link to ash, bash, dash, ksh, zsh, &c. (It will always be sh-compatible though – never csh or fish.)
- As long as you stick to sh features only, you can (and probably even should) use **#!/bin/sh** and the script should work fine, no matter which shell it is. https://superuser.com/a/1133205/284722
- You should only ever write shell scripts that work with any implementation of the shell language (including all the "utility" programs that go along with the shell itself). These days you can probably take POSIX.1-2001 (not -2008) as authoritative for what the shell and utilities are capable of, but be aware that you may one day be called upon to port your script to a legacy system (e.g. Solaris or AIX) whose shell and utilities were frozen circa 1992. https://superuser.com/a/1134898/284722
- Most portable: use a **#!/bin/sh** shebang and use only the basic shell syntax specified in the POSIX standard. This should work on pretty much any POSIX/unix/linux system. (Well, except Solaris 10 and earlier which had the real legacy Bourne shell, predating POSIX so noncompliant, as /bin/sh.) https://serverfault.com/a/865880/94862